# Compare whether the first two elements on a nested list are equal to a comparison list in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

In python 2.7, I would like to verify whether a subset list of elements is included in a longer nested list when comparing let's say only the first two elements.

Lets say we have a big list of nested elements (this big_list will have over 10k elements so looping for every comparison is very inefficient and I'd like to avoid this). For this example, lets say we only have 4 nested lists in big_list:

```
`
big_list = ((2,3,5,6,7), (4,5,6,7,8), (6,7,8,8), (8,4,2,7))
`
```

If I have a single list, let's say `(4,5,11,11,11)`, I am looking for an operation that will return True when compared to big_list since the second list in big_list starts with (4,5,...) and matches the first two elements of my single_list. Essentially I want to know whether the first two elements of a single list (e.g. (4,5,11,11,11)) are repeated in my big list regardless of the other followed numbers (e.g. 11,11, ...).

My operation should also return False if another single_list (e.g. `(4,8,11,11,11)` ) does not match the first two element in the big_list.

I hope this is clearer. Any help?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a huge list, to avoid iterating over the whole thing every time — O(n) time complexity for each search, you can do a constant time lookup using a set.

```
tup_truth_set = set([tup[:2] for tup in big_list]) # set with first two letters of interest
```

then you would simply do something like this to check in constant time:

```
tuple_of_interest[:2] in tup_truth_set
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can avoid the loop over your list. Even if you don't run the loop yourself and suppose there is a built-in function, *that I am not aware of* and can do what you are asking, I am pretty sure it would loop the list in the background. So I suggest a single line of code to do that, including a loop, **obviously**.

```
(4,5,11,11,11)[:2] in [i[:2] for i in big_list]
```